# Mailkit Office365 AcquireTokenInteractive requires client_secret

Tags: c#, office365, mailkit

So this is an issue that has been plaguing me for a bit and my deadline is coming up. I'm working on an application that sends emails and my workplace uses Office365 via Exchange. I'm using a C# webapp and using Mailkit to deliver emails.

The issue (not really an issue but good practice that's getting in my way) is that we made an email account to deliver mail yet our organization requires MFA. After talking about it with my director, creating an app password would not be a good idea for how this program is deployed so I'm trying to find ways to authenticate properly.

I eventually landed on using the Microsoft.Identity.Client library to require logging in via a registered Azure application. I could then cache this and refresh as needed, this way making sure the access is still valid.

However, I'm stuck on something. I have the app registration set to public with no client secrets or certificates with all of the necessary permissions. However right at the var oauth2 step, it fails while giving the error "Original exception: AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'."

The issue is that the application is public and is defined to allow public client flows. So I'm not getting how the request could still require a client secret when that's not how I'm building the request at all. I tried using private, but because of the MFA requirement, that fails too.

Below is what I have. Ignore that I'm hard coding stuff; it's temporary until I can get this sorted out. I'm also only scoping the SMTP permissions because all this application needs to do is send an email; IMAP isn't needed since it's not reading or anything else.

```
var options = new PublicClientApplicationOptions
{
    ClientId = "[clientID]",
    TenantId = "[tenandID]",
    RedirectUri = "http://localhost"
};

var publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
    .CreateWithApplicationOptions(options)
    .Build();

var scopes = new string[] {
    "email",
    "offline_access",
    "https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send" // Only needed for SMTP
};

var authToken = await publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

//Here is where it returns that it needs a client_secret and won't advance.
// The login window appears and states it was successfully authenticated,
// but the application crashes with that error at this step.
var oauth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(Config.Env.smtpUser, authToken.AccessToken);
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this? The deprecation of Basic Authentication article also states that app passwords for applications that don't use MFA will also not be supported.